# Code regarding exterior disconnects, outlets and fixtures

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, nec

What are the code requirements for wiring to outdoor disconnects, outlets and outdoor lighting fixtures?  I've usually just ran the type NM cable directly to the box. It seems difficult to transition from type NM to UF or individual wires (THHN/THWN) and have the connections be permanently accessible.

There's been quite a bit a chatter about this recently so I thought I'd post a direct question on this subject.

Including this question for context:   [How should transitions from inside to outside be handled when running a circuit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/214431/how-should-transitions-from-inside-to-outside-be-handled-when-running-a-circuit)

Comment: Keep in mind you don't *have* to transition.  You can run UF or THHN-in-conduit directly to the breaker panel just like you do with NM -- they're fine inside your house as well.  Or you can make a transition in a junction box anywhere before you exit the house -- the connections don't have to be accessible from outside specifically.